# object literal syntax oddity

Tags: javascript, object, syntax

I've always thought that objects need `{key:value}` pairings.

For example: `{ myProp:'1'}`

If so, why does this not give me a syntax error:

```
var test1 = { fn1, fn2 }
function fn1() {}
function fn2() {}
```

Comment: This would not throw error if your environment supports ES6

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is a valid ES6 [object definition syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Method_definitions),

```
var test1 = { fn1, fn2 }
function fn1() {}
function fn2() {}
```

The above code will be seen by the interpreter as,

```
var test1 = { "fn1" : fn1, "fn2" : fn2 }
function fn1() {}
function fn2() {}
```